# Thread blocks active per SM

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

How can I find that how many thread blocks will be potentially active at the same time on my 40kB Shared memory of gtx780?
how can I check the maximum occupancy per SM?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take a look around and see how to ask a valid and proper question.

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities     https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#multiprocessor-level

Comment: You can use the CUDA occupancy calculator https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls to calculate the theoretical value. You can run the CUDA profiler (Nsight VSE, Nsight Compute, or NV Visual Profiler) to see both the theoretical and the achieved occupancy.

Answer (score 2):

Maximum occupancy depends on your block size, number of registers needed by the kernel function per thread, and the amount of shared memory needed per block. Your could compute it yourself based on the device-specific limits, which you can query. If you're using a reasonably recent version of CUDA, the [driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__OCCUPANCY.html#group__CUDA__OCCUPANCY) as well as the [runtime API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OCCUPANCY.html#group__CUDART__OCCUPANCY) have functions for computing occupancy.

Note that you will only be able to compute the theoretical maximum occupancy. No matter how you compute that number, there is no *guarantee* that this is the actual number that will be run on the device at all times. Use this number as a guideline, e.g., to decide which launch configuration best to run. But do not write your code to depend on this particular number of blocks actually running concurrently. The only way to get a guaranteed number of blocks running concurrently is to use the fairly recent Cooperative Kernel Launch feature in CUDA 9+…